# difference between innerText vs innerHTML

Tags: javascript

Why `innerHTML` gives me `"2 #2 "` and `innerText` `"2 #2"`? the space is missed.

I believed `innerText` would gave me `"2 #2 "` as `innerHTML` too.
[image]

Just want to know the difference(if there is any difference) for this context, i know `innerHTML` is different, but is just text.

Comment: innerText stand for text data and InnerHTML for HTML data... surprised?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you are concerned why an extra space in one and not the other.

It can be easily reproduced by:

```js
const el = document.querySelector("#msg");

console.log(JSON.stringify(el.innerText));
console.log(JSON.stringify(el.innerHTML));
console.log(JSON.stringify(el.textContent));
```

```html
<div id="msg">hi there </div>
```

You can see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/innerText

> As a getter, it approximates the text the user would get if they highlighted the contents of the element with the cursor and then copied it to the clipboard.

so the space is not rendered according to the rules of HTML, and that's why `innerText` doesn't have the space at the end.

If your HTML is

```html
<div id="msg">
  hi there     
</div>
```

and with 5 spaces after the word `there`, the newline and spaces are all not rendered, so `innerText` would not give you those either.

You can also compare that to `textContent`, as quoted on the page above:

> Note: innerText is easily confused with Node.textContent, but there are important differences between the two. Basically, innerText is aware of the rendered appearance of text, while textContent is not.

You also can guess what the following will give out:

```js
const el = document.querySelector("#msg");

console.log(JSON.stringify(el.innerText));
console.log(JSON.stringify(el.innerHTML));
console.log(JSON.stringify(el.textContent));
```

```html
<div id="msg">hi    there </div>
```

So the answer is: when rendered, the spaces are collapsed together, so `innerText` gives you that version, while the other faithfully give you the one with multiple spaces.

Comment: prefer to test with `<div id="msg">hi   <span> there </span> </div>`....